# Combine styles passed down as props

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass down my styles as a prop? The style props dont show using the code below:

Container:

```
<StyledText
          text="Episode Overview"
          backgroundStyle={[styles.opacityBackground, { margin: 0 }]}
        />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column"
  },
  opacityBackground: { opacity: 0.8, backgroundColor: "#003333" },

});
```

Component

```
const StyledText = props => {
        let { text, backgroundStyle } = props;

        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, { ...backgroundStyle }]}>
                ...
            </View>
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass on the style as an object and not an array

```
 <StyledText
      text="Episode Overview"
      backgroundStyle={{...styles.opacityBackground, margin: 0 }}
    />



const StyledText = props => {
    let { text, backgroundStyle } = props;

    return (
        <View style={{...styles.container, ...backgroundStyle }}>
            ...
        </View>
    );
};
```